# Using ulink2 with nrf52840 and keil

Tags: arm, keil, nrf52832, nordic

I am trying to flash the blink example from SDK v15 into my custom nrf52840 board, I am using pc10056 example.

I connected my ulink2 to swdio, swclck, gnd and vcc of my custom board and I can see on my debug settings but when I try to flash I get Invalid ROM Table error, I tried to change

Here are my settings

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> the blink example

Which one? There is one for blank MCU and one for Softdevice.

There are Options missing:

```
Download Options
  [x] Download to flash

Download Function
   (x) Erase Sectors
```

Also, the NRF52x have only one MB of flash and not two.

Comment: I am using one without Softdevice. ```nRF5_SDK_15.3.0_59ac345\examples\peripheral\blinky\pca10056\blank\arm5_no_packs``` I tried mentioned download options and erase sectors but with no luck. For the flash memory I just used the pack installed for nrf52x